# Presenting effect modification in causal graphs

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, causality, causalml

I am quite new to causal inference and want to try some methods for treatment effect estimation. For this purpose, I created a the following data generation process in Python:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
X3 = np.random.randint(1,4, n)
X2 = np.random.randint(1,11, n)

X1 = 5 * X2 + 3 * X3 + np.random.randint(-1,3, n)
X4 = 10 * X2 + np.random.randint(-2,5, n)

#treatment probability
propensity = np.where(X1 > 30, 0.8, 0.2)
T = np.random.binomial(1, propensity)

#treatment effect
tau = np.where(X2 > 5, 10,0) * T * (-1)

#define outcome
Y = 50 * X2 - 5 * np.sqrt(X1) + T*tau + np.random.randint(10,21, n)
```

For the generated data, would created the following graph:

[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZlYT.png)

My question is: Since X2 (according to the data generation) does not influence the assignment of T but does have an influence on the treatment effect itself, is there an edge between X2 and T (X2->T) required?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that, in general, DAGs can only tell you what variables affect the other variables, but they can't tell you how they do that - they don't describe the functional form.

[There are several structural forms in which effect modification can arise](https://doi.org/10.1097/ede.0b013e318127181b), but the one in your data generation simulation matches the one you already drew in your DAG (X2 affects Y but not T).

If it's important for you to convey the interactions, [there are proposed DAG-based ways](https://doi.org/10.1097/EDE.0b013e318126c11d), but they are no longer valid DAGs.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you do not see a direct connection between X2 and T it does not mean that it has no influence in the assignment of T. As you set the rules of the data generation you know for a fact that X2 has some effect on T through X1, which is clear in the DAG.